# how do i loop an image to the full width/height of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to loop a small  image to 100% width of the page using a for loop.

```
var gameW = window.innerWidth;
var gameH = window.innerHeight;
var grass = document.getElementById("grass");
var sand = document.getElementById("sand");

grass.src = "images/grass.png"

function makeMap(){
    for(var i = 0; i < gameW; i++){
         grass++;
    }
}makeMap();
```

Comment: why you need to loop and what you want to do?

Comment: am sure you want to **duplicate** the image to the whole screen right ? but `grass++` ??

Comment: I want to make a map for a game but im not using canvas so im not going to use a tile map array approach. So i figured i would just be able to use a for loop to loop the tiles to the full width and height of the page.

Comment: yea i want to duplicate the image

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with css (if that is an option). [background-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) will probably do the job.

For example, you can add a single div that has the width of your viewport and set its background to the image you want.